# iOS CAShapeLayer and shadows with Core Animation

Tags: ios, core-graphics, core-animation, shadow

I would like to draw a graph with CAShapeLayer and set a pretty shadow on a background for some nice visual effect. With shadows, animation of my graph (straight line to graph modeled using some data) really slows down!. I read about shadowPath property and decided to use it, but the problem is, despite the fact wether I close the CGMutable path or not, it seems like CoreAnimation closes it, and this shadow I get, instead of a line, is rather a polygon. Looks really ugly.

Help!

Comment: Couldn't you just draw a clone of your line behind it in different color and offset it? Then you'd have a nice shadow without any complexity.

Comment: I'm sure you can. Anything is pretty much possible with Core Graphics. If you can't then going back to your original problem, you could make a polygon that is really really thing and looks like your line then maybe the shadow would behave like you're wanting.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about it, I was just looking for rather nicer solution to that problem :P

Comment: I find that when it comes to Core Graphics its always trial and error and making it work your way. As long as you're happy with it its the nicest solution possible lol